# Como retornar o 'ID pai (Principal)' nesta consulta MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando retornar o ID pai no nível mais alto em uma consulta, essas são as informações:

```
ID  NOME         PARENT_ID
1   Project      (null)
2   Sub          1
3   Sub-Sub      2
4   Sub-Sub-Sub  3
```

Eu preciso disto:

```
ID  NOME         PARENT_ID FATHER_ID
1   Project      (null)    (null)
2   Sub          1         1 
3   Sub-Sub      2         1
4   Sub-Sub-Sub  3         1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/993823/1)

Comment: Você quer retornar também o ID do pai "raíz", é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo @RodrigoRigotti

Comment: Não seria o próprio `FATHER_ID` ?

Comment: Quantos níveis?

Comment: FATHER_ID é o que eu preciso, eu só tenho o pai no primeiro nível. Preciso do pai geral. @AntonyAlkmim

Comment: @LeandroAmorim pode ter N níveis :(

Comment: E vc precisa disso em SQL mesmo, ou vai usar alguma linguagem cliente?

Comment: Preciso em SQL amigo @Bacco

Comment: @Bacco Eu tenho uma View das informações que preciso do Redmine e consumo a mesma por WSDL e a minha aplicação só envia os parâmetros e recebe a lista. Neste caso eu preciso filtrar todas as tarefas do usando somente o ID do projeto principal, para isso queria adicionar este campo na minha View.

Comment: @Bacco Tranquiloo! Com a procedure acredito que não ia dar certo, já a função acho que vai funcionar! Vou fazer um teste

Comment: @Bacco funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possível solução é uma função, mas se é uma coisa que vai ser muito usada, compensa ou acrescentar um campo na tabela para a categoria "master", e processar a árvore só nas modificações e inserções, ou então usar uma metodologia com *nodes* esquerdo e direito, para poder fazer a busca em árvore.

Segue uma função recursiva que vai localizando o nível superior e talvez possa ser adaptada ao caso real:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getRoot(idSearch INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  SET @idParent = idSearch;
  WHILE (@idParent != 0) DO
    SET @idFound = @idParent;
    SET @idParent = (SELECT id_parent FROM arvore WHERE id = @idParent);
  END WHILE;
  RETURN @idFound;
END
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2495c/1)**.

E com um JOIN mostrando a seção principal: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7620c/1)**.